# Dot Net Core not opening private key in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ssl, .net-core

**I can't get the private-key in the code what i'm doing wrong ?**

I tried 3 ways

- 1st way

  ```
  /etc/ssl/private/shop.org.key 
  /etc/ssl/certs/shop.org.crt
  ```
- 2nd way

  ```
  /usr/share/ca-certificates/shop.org.pem
  ```
- 3nd way

  ```
  /etc/ssl/certs/shop.org.pem
  ```

note : each time i deleted the old one and test for not getting the cert

**the c# code find the cert but not getting the private-key**

C# code

```
try

{

    X509Store store = new X509Store(
                            StoreName.CertificateAuthority,
                            StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

    var c = store.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                "84ACCDF55A43A3519322198B72B1ED46ABF44BD2",
                false)[0];

    var str = "";

    str += $"{c.Thumbprint}  {c.Verify()}";

    str += $"{c.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false)}";

    str += $"{c.HasPrivateKey} {c?.PrivateKey?.ToXmlString(true)}";

    Console.WriteLine(str);

}

catch (System.Exception ex)

{

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}
```

Output

```
84ACCDF55A43A3519322198B72B1ED46ABF44BD2  False  shop.org  False
```

/etc/ssl/private/shop.org.key file in

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

/etc/ssl/certs/shop.org.crt file in

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=AE, L=AE, O=AE, OU=AE, CN=CA_CommonName/emailAddress=d@d.d
        Validity
            Not Before: Dec 31 04:55:52 2018 GMT
            Not After : Dec 31 04:55:52 2019 GMT
        Subject: C=AE, ST=DU, L=Dubai, O=IT, OU=IT Department, CN=shop.org/emailAddress=webmaster@shop.org
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:bd:92:88:53:67:48:a6:54:21:2b:9f:e5:3e:a3:
                    f3:93:b5:ca:0e:a8:9f:0c:6f:84:86:3a:af:6d:ca:
                    b9:d6:06:82:53:b4:cb:a1:d4:bc:5b:a9:d1:a8:d6:
                    d3:97:61:bd:ff:fa:93:c5:67:0f:3a:b7:c6:bb:93:
                    47:5f:49:cf:f7:c7:1e:c2:24:c3:e3:04:9e:ef:f8:
                    e4:6e:66:58:08:6d:4e:17:95:b4:75:a6:db:68:7c:
                    e0:50:a0:83:66:e4:07:31:f4:41:74:94:d1:b3:7a:
                    eb:d7:4f:45:b7:b4:c3:18:36:84:01:83:38:60:55:
                    3b:8b:47:89:0d:93:b1:d3:3e:dc:ca:54:97:7e:ae:
                    37:65:df:10:62:a0:5e:ed:e9:c9:aa:4b:8d:dc:c5:
                    bb:40:8e:a4:3c:db:07:5c:8e:4b:f6:08:54:cd:eb:
                    7a:ca:ec:1b:67:a7:3d:a7:dc:18:34:a7:1b:2a:c9:
                    08:39:61:16:58:05:fe:37:9d:7d:ee:a4:1a:4e:e9:
                    61:d8:dd:a9:95:32:3b:f9:43:bf:c2:ac:ce:d7:1c:
                    70:70:30:b4:f9:7b:58:ff:85:b6:d7:28:3e:14:fa:
                    d2:43:c3:d1:29:0e:bb:70:fe:1e:8f:bc:3a:56:b0:
                    62:28:9a:94:ac:86:b6:e7:2b:f2:24:34:09:bb:da:
                    4c:83:81:42:e8:b9:92:44:0d:4f:08:d4:23:1c:4b:
                    93:8f:1d:73:bf:4c:17:5d:ec:13:77:fd:a5:2f:37:
                    b5:f0:a8:00:0d:0e:8d:f4:38:cd:91:cd:f4:f5:f5:
                    33:03:15:63:6f:d6:0e:c7:fb:ea:90:a5:3e:9f:07:
                    bc:77:3f:97:e2:f9:18:20:f9:86:1b:07:5e:b9:b2:
                    84:cb:f0:6d:50:cf:35:09:8a:99:cb:61:a6:5a:7f:
                    cd:48:4a:56:b3:d7:ca:4d:4c:c1:b7:02:07:59:ed:
                    0d:1b:62:f4:06:9b:0c:d6:18:ed:83:23:cc:2f:4e:
                    ec:e1:f9:23:ed:04:6b:d3:f9:04:b5:2c:b3:17:0c:
                    02:93:26:a3:0f:76:1b:d3:78:fa:88:37:95:60:64:
                    22:87:ef:95:3f:b5:c3:f0:13:e8:d0:31:27:e0:d7:
                    34:3b:23:a2:00:0c:1f:c0:4d:88:6a:c5:2f:e4:b1:
                    93:d3:84:2b:af:84:b2:54:b3:cc:14:17:20:60:e6:
                    4a:f0:3a:03:11:bb:5e:35:36:73:86:79:9b:c5:cc:
                    52:c3:6f:66:ca:d3:84:50:0d:e5:20:30:22:fe:13:
                    57:65:53:cd:25:f5:18:4c:48:73:fc:31:0a:a8:6a:
                    64:e3:b9:f9:13:0e:8a:73:cc:aa:5d:19:b6:2c:52:
                    c7:39:eb
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Comment: 
                OpenSSL Generated Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                49:55:99:BC:39:32:96:75:7A:56:63:72:AB:D8:A5:93:68:DD:2B:3D
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:3F:BD:45:6E:B2:BB:A6:1C:64:3B:CB:1C:76:4C:16:22:3E:18:2E:09

            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.shop.org, DNS:shop.org
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        7f:3c:b8:96:43:32:5d:19:a0:66:7a:bc:1e:12:ac:95:22:5f:
        80:19:9f:fb:73:03:58:ae:62:c8:52:e1:ec:0a:b0:3a:0f:69:
        f3:aa:ad:82:f1:c9:fa:97:d8:ef:62:36:23:8f:2b:1a:77:bb:
        86:ef:5d:68:83:c4:74:71:68:99:b4:a9:f5:94:f4:81:ef:34:
        c2:ca:00:57:91:76:4e:68:94:35:b4:3e:34:80:18:cc:ae:53:
        e7:b3:4a:af:58:be:17:9c:60:36:91:54:35:6e:23:02:37:26:
        f7:d0:a2:16:1d:d0:b2:1a:3f:c0:70:b9:41:aa:36:21:60:7e:
        21:8d:ef:d6:58:d2:02:9b:ef:3d:31:bb:fe:ed:15:bf:6f:fb:
        df:9e:00:2c:1f:bd:2d:0a:dc:e7:71:5d:b4:cf:09:24:6d:fd:
        5f:18:2d:6d:a8:51:37:be:ad:b5:b0:d0:b9:d0:81:45:ee:c7:
        06:53:1a:06:6c:06:28:4f:f1:1a:79:1b:ce:00:f8:d5:00:45:
        ca:f1:d5:31:74:de:b2:28:23:8f:e0:8c:c8:51:ff:1e:5c:6b:
        eb:c1:9a:b6:ca:d2:94:37:88:ce:4d:05:03:e0:7c:9c:7b:73:
        d6:75:c6:dc:7b:4a:68:58:0f:05:ee:03:df:14:0e:24:f2:b5:
        56:b3:92:91
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

PEM with private Key in /usr/share/ca-certificates/shop.org.pem

also tried /etc/ssl/certs/shop.org.pem

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 84 AC CD F5 5A 43 A3 51 93 22 19 8B 72 B1 ED 46 AB F4 4B D2 
subject=/C=AE/ST=DU/L=Dubai/O=IT/OU=IT Department/CN=shop.org/emailAddress=webmaster@shop.org
issuer=/C=AE/L=AE/O=AE/OU=AE/CN=CA_CommonName/emailAddress=d@d.d
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 84 AC CD F5 5A 43 A3 51 93 22 19 8B 72 B1 ED 46 AB F4 4B D2 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: i hope you will be changing your keys after this post. you did not have to post the entire key

Comment: thanks @NevilleNazerane , the private key used just for this question